# CSS - design view in dreamweaver is ok, but not in the browser

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, margin

So, I have this css code to format a html page. The problem is that, when I view the page in the browser, I get it as not formated at all. Div's titulo and titulo2 are simples text lines and the formulario's div is a form. I want the form to be centered to the page, with a margin-left and right auto.

Thanks

```
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */

    #titulo{
        background:white;
        text-align:center;
    };

    #titulo2{
        background:white;
        text-align:center;
    };

   #formulario{
        margin-left: auto ;
        margin-right: auto ;
        width: 400px;
        display: inline-block;
    };
```

Ok, so here is my html:

```
<body>

<p>
<div id="titulo">Área Pessoal</div>
</p>

<p>
<div id="titulo2">Registo de Saídas</div>
</p>

<div id="formulario"><form>

<p>
<label>Data e hora : <input /></label>
</p>

<p>
<label>Morada : <input /></label>
</p>
<p>
<label>Localização Geográfica : <input /></label>
</p>

<p>
<label>Tipo de saída : <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Sozinho" />Sozinho</label><input type="radio" name="tipo" value="Acompanhado" />Acompanhado</label>
</p>

<p>
<label>Condições Atmosféricas : <input /></label>
</p>

<p>
<label>Altura da maré : <input type="radio" name="mare" value="Alta" />Alta</label><input type="radio" name="mare" value="Baixa" />Baixa</label>
</p>

<p>
<label>Temperatura da Água : <input  /></label>
</p>

<p>
<label>Visibilidade Dentro de Água :  <input type="radio" name="visibilidade" value="Boa" />Boa</label><input type="radio" name="visibilidade" value="Má" />Má</label>
</p>

<p>
<label>Peixes Capturados : </label>
</p>
<p>
<label>espécies <input type="text" /></label>
</p>
<p>
<label>compimento <input type="text" /></label>
</p>
<p>
<label>peso <input type="text" /></label>
</p>
<p>
<label>Upload Ficheiros Multimédia :<br />
  <input type="file" name="ficheiro" multiple>
    </label>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar"><input type="reset"></p>

</form></div>

<p>
<label><a href="historico_saidas.html">Histórico de Saídas</a></label>
</p>
<p>
<label><a href="estatisticas.html">Estatisticas</a></label>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe the HTML isn't including the CSS file properly?

Comment: You need to show the entire code.

Comment: Are you talking about this ? "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="registo_saidas.css" />" This is right, the first "titulo" I get centered as I want, but not the rest of the page

Comment: Put the form inside a div then make the div centered... I've seen problems with formatting forms centerally.

Comment: The form is inside his own div...

Comment: Do you have a `reset` stylesheet?

Comment: What do you mean by a reset stylesheet ? Sorry, but I never heard about it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be obvious, but are your divs labelled correctly?
Example `<div id="titulo"></div>`

You've got closing tags after the style, but after that the easist way is probably to wrap everything with a div

```
#titulo { background:white; text-align:center; } 
#titulo2{ background:white; text-align:center; } 
#formulario{ margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto ; width: 400px; display: inline-block; }
.wrapper{ width:600px; margin:0 auto; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
<div id="titulo"><p>Área Pessoal</p></div> 
<div id="titulo2"><p>Registo de Saídas</p></div> 
<div id="formulario">
```

etc..

Comment: Almost there, but i'm still with the same problem in titulo2. In DW, is centered but on chrome is on the left of the div...

Comment: Try this: #titulo2{ background:white; margin:0 auto; }

Comment: Same problem...
I'm now with this:

    .wrapper{ 
     width: 400px;
     height:: 4000px;
     margin-left: auto ;
     margin-right: auto ;
    };

#titulo{
 text-align:center;
};

#titulo2{
 text-align:center;
}

#formulario{
 margin-left: auto ; 
 margin-right: auto ;
};

And I get the main div centered with all its content but both titles are next to the left border of it...

Comment: Perhaps center the p text?     .wrapper{ width: 400px; height:4000px; margin: 0 auto; }; #titulo{ text-align:center }; #titulo2{ text-align:center; } #formulario{ margin:0 auto ; }
 #titulo p, #titulo2 p{ text-align:center; }

Comment: nothing changes...i'll keep trying to find how to solve it, but I'm running out of ideas...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, 1) Never use Dreamweaver as your source of seeing how HTML/CSS is complied, always run it in a browser... Too many reasons to discuss. 2) You will need to wrap the form in a div element, and assign it a set width (and height depending on how your form is set out). Once thats done, then assign the div the margin:auto properties...

Comment: I think that was what I did, right ? And I'm still with the same problem

Comment: It's because Dreamweaver often doesn't render HTML properly. On my website, elements seem to be in complete disarray in Dreamweaver, but look good in-browser.

Comment: Mine is the other way around, nice in DW but ugly in broswer :p

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the link tag has a root-relative reference.

For example, if I had this:

```
includes/gallery.css
```

then the link may appear as follows:

```
<link href="/includes/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This will not render correctly if the "gallery.css" file is not in the following location:

```
[root directory]/includes/gallery.css
```

To fix this problem, one could add a period to the path like this:

```
<link href="./includes/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or remove the initial forward slash like this:

```
<link href="includes/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This would work for a html page that is one directory up from includes. For example, for the index.html page:

[image: Example web folder structure]

The way the browser locates the gallery.css file in this case is in the following manner:

1. From the directory that index.html is currently in (Site)
2. Move down one level to the directory "includes"
3. Get the file "gallery.css"

I hope this helps.

Regards - Wayne Riesterer